# Fine tuning CNN hyperparameters for complex text classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, text-classification, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a **CNN model** for complex text classification (mainly emails and messages). The dataset contains around 100k entries distributed on 10 different classes. My actual Keras sequential model has the following structure:

```
model = Sequential(
        [
            Embedding(
                input_dim=10000,
                output_dim=150,
                input_length=400),
            Convolution1D(
                filters=128,
                kernel_size=4,
                padding='same',
                activation='relu'),
                BatchNormalization(),
            MaxPooling1D(),
            Flatten(),
            Dropout(0.4),
            Dense(
                100,
                activation='relu'),
            Dropout(0.4),
            Dense(
                len(y_train[0]),
                activation='softmax')])
```

In compiling the model I'm using the **Nadam optimizer**, **categorical_crossentropy** loss with **LabelSmoothing** set to 0.2 .

In a model fit, I'm using **30 Epochs** and **Batch Size** set to **512**. I also use **EarlyStopping** to monitor val_loss and patience set to 8 epochs. The test size is set to 25% of the dataset.

Actually the training stops after 16/18 epochs with values that start to fluctuate a little after 6/7 epoch and then go on till being stopped by EarlyStopping. The values are like these on average:

*loss: 1.1673 - accuracy: 0.9674 - val_loss: 1.2464 - val_accuracy: 0.8964*

with a testing accuracy reaching:

*loss: 1.2461 - accuracy: 0.8951*

Now I'd like to improve the accuracy of my CNN, I've tried different hyperparameters but as for now, I wasn't able to get a higher value. Therefore I'm trying to figure out:

1. if there is still room for improvements (I bet so)
2. if the solution is in a fine-tuning of my hyperparameters and, if so, which ones should I change?
3. if going deeper by adding layers to the model could be of any use and, if so, how to improve my model
4. is there any other deep-learning/Neural networks approach rather than CNN that could lead to a better result?

Thank you very much to anybody who will help! :)

Comment: Consider using either Grid Search or Bayesian optimization through Gaussian processes of the hyperparameters for tuning your model.

Comment: Also, you could consider using LSTM NN for this sort of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries, but I find this one very flexible. https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner

**Just install with pip.**

Your updated model, feel free to choose the search range.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch


def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=hp.Int('input_dim',
                                        min_value=5000,
                                        max_value=10000,
                                        step = 1000),
                              output_dim=hp.Int('output_dim',
                                        min_value=200,
                                        max_value=800,
                                        step = 100),
                              input_length = 400))
    model.add(layers.Convolution1D(
                filters=hp.Int('filters',
                                        min_value=32,
                                        max_value=512,
                                        step = 32),
                kernel_size=hp.Int('kernel_size',
                                        min_value=3,
                                        max_value=11,
                                        step = 2),
                padding='same',
                activation='relu')),
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D())
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',
                                        min_value=64,
                                        max_value=256,
                                        step=32),
                           activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(layers.Dense(y_train[0], activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
        hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                  values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


tuner = RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=5,
    executions_per_trial=3,
    directory='my_dir',
    project_name='helloworld')
tuner.search_space_summary()

## The following lines are based on your model


tuner.search(x, y,
             epochs=5,
             validation_data=(val_x, val_y))

models = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=2)
```

You can try replacing the Conv1D layers with LSTM layers and observe if you get better performance.

`LSTM(units = 512)` https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

If you want to extract more meaningful features, one approach I found promising is by extracting pre-trained BERT features and then training using a CNN/LSTM.

A great repository to get started is this one - 
https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers

Once you get the sentence embedding from the BERT/XLNet you can use those features to train another CNN similar to the one you are using except maybe get rid of the embedding layer as it's expensive.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try this approach tomorrow! I'll let you know how it performs! :)

Comment: @TheOldMan if the answer helps you kindly upvote/accept. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers